# Vertices of quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

I came across an interesting question online that was about vertices of quadrilaterals.  I am still stumped as to how to find the answer of this solution.

The question I found was:

**Is it possible to find 4 points that are the vertices of 2 different convex quadrilaterals?  If so, what is the maximum number of convex quadrilaterals that can have the same set of vertices?**

I do not think that it is possible to find 4 points that are the vertices of 2 different convex quadrilaterals, but I am not sure if what I think is wrong or right?  If my conclusion is right, could someone explain why please?

Thank you very much.

Michael Silva

Answer (score 0):

The only convex quadrilateral with this vertices may be defined as intersection of all convex sets containing them. So the answer is 1.